# How can I acces the output from the first select statement

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table Like this

```
Col1 | Col2
-----------
a    | d
b    | e
c    | a
```

Now I want to create an statement to get an output like this:

```
First| Second
-------------------
a    | Amsterdamm
b    | Berlin
c    | Canada
...
```

So far I have this consturct what is not working

```
SELECT *
FROM(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        CASE
            when Col1 IS NULL then 'NA' 
            else Col1
        END
        FROM Table1
    UNION
        SELECT DISTINCT
        CASE
            when Col2 IS NULL then 'NA' 
            else Col2
        END
    FROM Table1
    ) AS First
    ,
    (   
    SELECT DISTINCT
        when First= 'a' then 'Amsterdam'
        when First= 'b' then 'Berlin'
        when First= 'c' then 'Canada'
    ) AS Second
;
```

can you help me with that

Sorry I have to edit my question to be more specific.

Comment: "What is not working"...you tell us.

Comment: what results do you currently get?

Comment: I get only error-Messages, I don't know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not as familiar with DB2... I'll lookup if it has a [concat function](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000781.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-3-2-25) in a sec... and it does.

```
SELECT First, case when first = 'a' then 
                    concat('This is a ',first)
              case when first = 'b' then 
                    concat('To Be or not to ',first)
              case else  
                    concat('This is a ',first) end  as Second
FROM (
  SELECT coalesce(col1, 'NA') as First 
  FROM Table
  UNION
  SELECT coalesce(col2, 'NA') 
  FROM table) SRC
WHERE first <> 'NA'
```

What this does is generate a single inline view called `src` with a column called `first`.  If `col1` or `col2` of `table` are null then it substitutes NA for that value.  It then concatenates `first` and the desired text excluding records with a `first` value of 'NA'

Or if you just create an inline table with the desired values and join in...

```
    SELECT First,  x.b as Second
    FROM (
      SELECT coalesce(col1, 'NA') as First 
      FROM Table
      UNION
      SELECT coalesce(col2, 'NA') 
      FROM table) SRC
    INNER JOIN (select a,b 
                from (values ('a', 'This is a'), 
                             ('b', 'To B or not to' ), 
                             ('c', 'I like cat whose name starts with')) as x(a,b)) X;
   on X.a = src.first
    WHERE first <> 'NA'
```

Personally I find the 2nd option easier to read.  Though if you have meaning for a,b,c I would think you'd want that stored in a table somewhere for additional access.  In code seems like a bad place to store data like this that could change.
Assuming you want

```
a this is a a 
b this is a b 
c this is a c 
d this is a d
e this is a e
```

Comment: can I also variate the text in the contact function? 
a | amsterdam, b | berlin

Comment: Yes using a case statement or create a table with the different values and join it in with the appropriate substitution.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to xQbert
I could solve this problem like this

```
SELECT FirstRow, concat
(
CASE FirstRow
WHEN 'AN' then 'amerstdam'
WHEN 'G' then 'berlin'
ELSE 'NA'
END, ''
) AS SecondRow
FROM(
    Select coalesce (Col1, 'NA') as FirstRow 
    FROM Table1
    UNION
    Select coalesce (Col2, 'NA')
    FROM Table1) SRC
WHERE FirstRow <> 'NA'
;
```

Comment: Note if you want to handle case 'NA' and display the record/row then you need to eliminate my where clause in the sub-select.  It seems to me those values AN, G, NA should all be in a table that you could simply join to.  I still recommend having those values in a table rather than code!  You don't want to have to change code when AN becomes `New Ansterdam`